# can nodejs connection be affected by the type of router i use?

Tags: node.js

Hi i have a nodejs server running on windows and 5 esp8266 as my client. I have 2 routers in the office, i have no problem or what so ever with the first router, it connects to my wifi and then it connects to the node server seamlessly but with the 2nd router the devices are only connecting to the wifi but not to the node server. is there something that i should configure with the router? is it even possible for the clients to be affected by the type or router or some configurations in the router?

Comment: What type of server identifier are you using?  IP address?  locally configured hostname?  DNS name?  Are both client and server on the office network?

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm using ip address and yes they are on the same office network

Comment: Well, there absolutely can be obstacles between different parts of the same office network.  This can be configurations of a router that doesn't allow one to connect from one segment of the office network to another or it can be an actual firewall set up between parts of the network.

Answer (score 0):

yes, It Is possible.
Check if there is some option like "*client isolation*"
A Router may prevent one device from connecting with other in local network.
read more [Here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16751/wireless-client-isolation-how-does-it-work-and-can-it-be-bypassed)